# Cannot load an RTF file's text into a RichTextBox?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to load a RichTextBox using an RTF file that is embedded as a resource:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click( _
    ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.RichTextBox1.Text = Global.MyApp.My.Resources.RTFFile
```

But when I do this, the RTF's markup isn't interpreted, and the RTB displays the following:

> {\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1251\uc1\adeff0\deff0\stshfdbch37\stshfloch37\stshfhich37\stshfbi0\deflang1049\deflangfe1049\themelang1049\themelangfe0\themelangcs0{\fonttbl{\f0\fbidi \froman\fcharset204\fprq2{*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\f34\fbidi \froman\fcharset1\fprq2{*\panose 02040503050406030204}Cambria Math;}
>   {\f37\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2{*\panose 020f0502020204030204}Calibri;}{\f38\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2{*\panose 020b0604030504040204}Tahoma;}

It works when I load the RTF file from disk:

```
Form2.Show()
Form2.RichTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\1.rtf")
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please review my edits.  You'll see how to format code and to quote text.  The editor has extensive help as well, just click that `?` on the far right side.

Comment: Simple mistake: set the Rtf property, not the Text property.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the rich text through the load method like you do when it's a file. This can be done through the overload with the stream

I found the following csharp - code through http://www.csharp411.com/display-an-rtf-file-thats-a-c-embedded-resource/

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream( "MyNamespace.FileName.rtf" );

RichTextBox rt = new RichTextBox();
rt.LoadFile( stream, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText );
```

This has to be translated into VB.NET.. something like this. 
remember to include system.reflection

```
dim asm as Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
dim stream as Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream( "MyNamespace._1.rtf" )
Form2.RichTextBox1.LoadFile(stream,  RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText )
```

Hope it works